# Better contrast for flag count

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

The flag counter in our moderation tools offers a generous contrast of 2% (two percent). This is almost unreadable. May I ask for a contrast of *at least* 10%?

[image]

### Update 23.03.2012

I have added the following rule to my user style sheet:

```
.supernovabg
{
    background: #505    !important;
}
```

Result

[image]

Could we get this as default? *Please!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have darkened the text in the mod indicator for better contrast. The change will be in the next production build.