# Flag count numbers are hard to read again

Tags: bug, design, moderation

We had this problem [some years ago](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/994/better-contrast-for-flag-count), now it is back: the flag count in the moderator dashboard is barely readable.

[image]

It is not just the contrast: the letter spacing and the pure font size are also too small.

Looking at that table, I wonder why the mod names need to be surrounded by all that extra information: chat badges, site badges separated by color, reputation. None of that is relevant.